# drop down list formula in Quickbase

Tags: quickbase

I have a simple question : Is it possible to fill a drop down list with two value from a table?

I have a table with field X and field Y and I want my drop down in my form to show :

```
Value1 YField - Value1 XField
Value2 YField - Value2 XField
Value3 YField - Value3 XField
...
```

Or I have not choice but to add another drop down to select my value from and put a Text (formula) field under it using its value to build what I want?

I would like to avoid overloading the form if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solve my problem :

What I did is add a field in my table with the concatenate value

```
YField - XField
```

So in my drop down list I link a reference to that field.